# Presenting data by categories

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Hello to all the pros out there,

Im doing a project for school where i am categorizing videos (links to youtube) submmited by users to my site.

one of the the videos properties is the "Creator name".

Lets say i have unkown number of content produsers (aka Creator Name). the user can subscribe to a specific (one or more) content producers.

in a dedicated page, the user can see list of his subscriptions (Creator Name) and under each Creator Name see a list of recentley submmited videos.

Something like this:

```
Some Name:

Video link 1

Video link 2

Some other name:

Video link 1

Video link 2
```

i am using database and have those tables:

- UserSubscription(User_ID,Creator_ID)
- VideoDetails(Video_ID, Video_Name, Creator_ID)
- Creator(Creator_ID,Creator_Name)

i would like only the general idea/approach to this problem. 
thank you very much

elli

Comment: What exactly is your question? From your explanation I think your database structure is a fairly good starting point so what are you having trouble with?

Comment: i have a trouble with the implementation. i was trying to use Nested Datalists, for the outer Datalist (the one that will show the creator name) i wrote a DISTINCT SQL query for the UserSubscription table, that was fine, i got the creators name. the problem is how to use each name for the inner query to get only the videos by this creator. i am using SQLDataSourse, and i dont want to create tons of SQLDatasourses in my page for each creator. is this makes any sense?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would say that if you only want to display a list of links I would not use a DataList - instead use Repeaters. This is an excellent article to help you make your decision http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479015.aspx.

This should get you started whichever one you choose http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306154

Comment: the thing is, i am not using a list of links, i am using my usercontrol, i gave the example using link to simplify the explanation. i will check those articles